# laravel login check is false after login

Tags: php, laravel

User login in app using JWT token then i want to create a link that user can open in browser and automatically login into his account so i send JWT token in query string.

I send JWT token to server then login user manually.

```
$jwt = request()->jwt;  
$user = auth('api')->setToken($jwt)->user();
Auth::login($user);

Auth::check(); // true
```

but after this request in another route user is not logged in!

```
Auth::check() // false
```

Comment: what are those special characters    at the end of first line?

Comment: @aimme i don't see any special character... can you send screenshot?

Comment: should i post it as an answer? cos i cant post it as a comment?

Comment: Does the route have the same middleware? You're using the API guard; does the other route use the same guard?

Comment: @ceejayoz this route is in web.php i just manually use api guard to get the token from query string and get user id then i want to login this user in web guard

Comment: @ceejayoz in fact i want to create a link that from app user can login in web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i didn't return response so it didn't set cookie and session was not creating. so i fixed it by returning a response like this:

```
return response();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I see some special characters

[image]

Comment: oh that's really strange

Comment: ya. i thought same way. so I mentioned it.